# Nominatim reverse geocoding Json format difference

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to do reverse geocoding using open street maps. I am getting 2 different Json formats in the response.

For, http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?json_callback=cb&format=json&lat=12.975360&lon=80.190122&zoom=27&addressdetails=1 The Response contains neigbourhood,suburb etc,.

For,http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?json_callback=cb&format=json&lat=40.119198&lon=-75.355764&zoom=27&osm_type=N&addressdetails=1 The Response contains county and other fields.

I do see that the OSM_TYPE is differing in both the response(node/way). Is there any way to restrict the type of response?I tried to add OSM_TYPE in the query string which doesn't seem to work. Is there anyother format that could be received?

Comment: The different fields in the response have nothing to do with the osm_type. Different parts in the world have different levels of detail in OSM (and other geocoders).

Comment: cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42736283/1340631

Comment: @scai - what is the best way to handle the data if different fields are in the response? Is there any documentation for various levels of detail sent back by OSM?

Comment: According to the Nominatim documentation the [hierarchy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Hierarchy) should correspond to the [admin_level](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative) tag of boundary=administrative relations. The admin level values have different meanings depending on the country.

Comment: cross-posted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55051/reverse-geocoding-json-format-difference